# In amCharts ensure irregular intervals on x-axis between data points when not using dates

Tags: amcharts

I have a line graph with an X axis, with data that doesn't correspond to a dates but are numerical values.

I'd like my x-axis to have it's content appropriately spaced according to it's value on the axis.

However, as you will see in the example, there's equal spacing between each datapoint even though there are unequal jumps in the value on the x axis.

https://jsfiddle.net/shwaydogg/xfxk5gwu/3/

```
"dataProvider": [
    {
    x:1, 
    visits: 1,  
  },        {
    x:1.1, 
    visits: 2,  
  },        {
    x:1.3, 
    visits: 3,  
  },        {
    x:5, 
    visits: 4,  
  },        {
    x:10, 
    visits: 5,  
  },        {
    x:100, 
    visits: 6,  
  },        {
    x:10000, 
    visits: 7,  
  },        {
    x:100000, 
    visits: 8,  
  },
],
```

note: I am aware of [equalSpacing](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#equalSpacing), but it's default value is false, it has not changed anything for me yet and seems to be geared towards keeping equal spacing if you are using parseDates which I am not.

Comment: What about using a XY Chart? [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wws3u9nh/)

Answer (score 0):

An official response from the amCharts support team shows how to use XY Chart as @gerric indicated correctly:

> Serial charts are not appropriate if you're using a numeric x-axis as the categoryAxis uses the exact values for each tick like string-based categories. You'll want to use an XY chart instead, which will create a full numeric x-axis with appropriate scaling.
>
> I made some minor modifications to your existing chart here: https://jsfiddle.net/xfxk5gwu/4/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "xy",
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an XY chart that loses some of the features of the serial chart I opted for a bit of a hack.  In the dataprovider I added all the missing x-axis values without giving them a y-value (a value that corresponded with one of the lines).  e.g.:

```
"dataProvider": [
  {
    x:1, 
    visits: 0,  
  },{        
    x:1.25, 
    visits: 1,  
  },{
    x:1.75, 
    visits: 2,  
  },{
    x:2.25, 
    visits: 3,  
  }
]
```

changed to =>

```
"dataProvider": [
  {        
    x:1, 
    visits: 0,  
  },{  
    x:1.25, 
    visits: 1,  
  },{        
    x:1.5       //Added
  },{
    x:1.75, 
    visits: 2,  
  },{        
    x:2         //Added
  },{
    x:2.25, 
    visits: 3,  
  }
]
```